# difficulties with program

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to get my program to run through different difficulties by using if statements, but I'm coming across a few errors.  I am also having issues with my `public static int[]`.  I was trying to find a way to get rid of it completely and have each array be set in its own if statement.

```
import java.util.*;

class CAI {
    public static void main (String[] arguments) {
        menu();//calls menu method
        compute();//calls compute method
    }
    public static void menu() {//method that displays menu
        System.out.println (" CAI MENU " );
        System.out.println ("\n1) DIFFICULTY 1\n2) DIFFICULTY 2\n3) DIFFICULTY 3\n4) DIFFICULTY 4\n5)DIFFICULTY 5");
    }
    public static int[] Blop(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int arr[] = new int[4];
        arr[0] = rand.nextInt(9);
        arr[1] = rand.nextInt(9);
        arr[3] = rand.nextInt(99);
        arr[4] = rand.nextInt(99);
        return arr;
    }
    public static void compute(){
        int option;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an option: ");
        option = input.nextInt();
        while (option != 0){
            if(option == 1){
                int num[] = new int[2];
                int ans;
                String choice;
                do{
                    num = Blop();
                    do{
                        System.out.print("How much is " + num[0] + " times " + num[1] + " ? :");
                        ans = input.nextInt();
                        String Correct;
                        String Wrong;
                        String[] correct = {"Very good! ","Excellent! ","Nice work! ","Keep up the good work! "};
                        String[] wrong = {"No. Please try again. ","Wrong. Try once more. ","Don’t give up! ","No. Keep trying "};
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        Correct = correct[rand.nextInt(correct.length)];
                        Wrong = wrong[rand.nextInt(wrong.length)];
                        if(ans == (num[0]*num[1])){
                            System.out.print(Correct);
                        }else{
                            System.out.print(Wrong);
                        }
                    }while(ans != (num[0]*num[1]));
                    System.out.print("Do you want more questions(yes/no) :");
                    input.nextLine();
                    choice = input.nextLine();
                }while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
            }
            if(option == 2){
                int num[] = new int[2];
                int ans;
                String choice;
                do{
                    num = Blop();
                    do{
                        System.out.print("How much is " + num[2] + " times " + num[3] + " ? :");
                        ans = input.nextInt();
                        String Correct;
                        String Wrong;
                        String[] correct = {"Very good! ","Excellent! ","Nice work! ","Keep up the good work! "};
                        String[] wrong = {"No. Please try again. ","Wrong. Try once more. ","Don’t give up! ","No. Keep trying "};
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        Correct = correct[rand.nextInt(correct.length)];
                        Wrong = wrong[rand.nextInt(wrong.length)];
                        if(ans == (num[2]*num[3])){
                            System.out.print(Correct);
                        }else{
                            System.out.print(Wrong);
                        }
                    }while(ans != (num[2]*num[3]));
                    System.out.print("Do you want more questions(yes/no) :");
                    input.nextLine();
                    choice = input.nextLine();
                }while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of a code dump here. Mind distilling it down to the basics/the minimum structure needed for us to understand the question?

Comment: Please spell out your exact questions.

Comment: Your `Blop` function should throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException` : indexes are not set correctly (0, 1, __3__, __4__) instead of (0, 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate your Object `CAI` then you can do away with static methods

eg.

```
public static void main (String[] arguments) {

    CAI myCai = new CAI();
    myCai.menu();//calls menu method
    myCai.compute();//calls compute method
}

private void menu() {//method that displays menu
    System.out.println (" CAI MENU " );
    System.out.println ("\n1) DIFFICULTY 1\n2) DIFFICULTY 2\n3) DIFFICULTY 3\n4) DIFFICULTY 4\n5)DIFFICULTY 5");
}
```

Also you have an error

```
private int[] Blop(){
  Random rand = new Random();
  int arr[] = new int[4];
  arr[0] = rand.nextInt(9);
  arr[1] = rand.nextInt(9);
  arr[2] = rand.nextInt(99);  // change index
  arr[3] = rand.nextInt(99);  // change index
```

As the above code is now non-static, it executed within each instance of the class, it is local only to the instantiated class.  Each instance will execute this code separately.